# Minimum polynomial of (2n,2n) matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The question is minimul polynomial of $(2n,2n)$ matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
is $t^3 - n^2t$ ($t$ is variable nad 2 $\leq$ $n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $J$ be the $n\times n$ all-1's  matrix.

A simple calculation shows that the minimal polynomial of $J$ is $t(t-n)$.

Hence the minimal polynomial of $-J$ is $t(t+n)$.

The matrix in the question is clearly similar to $\begin{pmatrix}J & O\\O&-J\end{pmatrix}$. It is therefore killed by the least common multiple of the minimal polynomials of $J$ and $-J$, that is $t(t^2-n^2)$; and is clearly not killed by any proper divisor.

Hence the minimal polynomial is as required.